# Context.MkSolver() Changes between Z3 versions 4.1 and 4.3

Tags: .net, z3

Recently I was upgrading an application that uses the .NET API from Z3 version 4.1 to version 4.3.  However, I noticed there has been a change in `MkSolver()` that now causes some of my queries that returned `unsat` in 4.1 to now return `unknown` in 4.3.  In particular, I had been using the `Context` option `ELIM_QUANTIFIERS` set to true, which has been deprecated according to an error message I receive when trying to use the solver:

`QUANT_ELIM option is deprecated, please consider using the 'qe' tactic.`

Without this option enabled, some of my queries may receive unknown.  I have tried using a variety of tactics in 4.3, including the quantifier elimination `qe`, but unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out an equivalent set of tactics to what MkSolver in Z3 4.1 created.  For example, the following does not work (i.e., I still get unknown in 4.3 for queries that I got unsat for in 4.1):

```
Context z3 = new Context();
Params p = z3.MkParams();
p.Add("produce-models", true);
p.Add("candidate-models", true);
p.Add("mbqi", true);
p.Add("auto-config", false);
p.Add("ematching", true);
p.Add("pull-nested-quantifiers", true);
Tactic tqe = z3.With(z3.MkTactic("qe"), p);
Tactic tsmt = z3.With(z3.MkTactic("smt"), p);
Tactic t = z3.Repeat(tqe, tsmt);
Solver s = t.Solver;
... // assert and check assertions
```

If there is an equivalent solver-tactic in 4.3 to what `MkSolver` created in 4.1, what is it or how can I go about figuring it out?  I used a variety of other context options in 4.1, which I have tried to use in the appropriate tactics in 4.3, such as: `MBQI = true`, `AUTO_CONFIG = false`, `ELIM_NLARITH_QUANTIFIERS = true`, `EMATCHING = true`, `MACRO_FINDER = true`, `PI_PULL_QUANTIFIERS = true`, `PULL_NESTED_QUANTIFIERS = true`, `DISTRIBUTE_FORALL = true`, and `PULL_NESTED_QUANTIFIERS = true`.

Here is an example query that now returns `unknown`, which previously returned `unsat` (note that it is unsat only with some additional assertions, which are quite long, but this is the format of the assertion that now gives unknown. Here `LB`, `LS`, `vmin`, and `vmax` are all real constants [with assertions equating them to constant values, e.g., `LS = 7`], and `q` is a function from integers to bitvectors, `x` is a function from integers to reals, `next` is a function from integers to integers, and `last` is an integer, and likewise for their primed versions; also, note that part of it is nonlinear, e.g., `delta * t_1` and `delta * t_2`):

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
;(set-option :elim-quantifiers true)
(set-option :elim-nlarith-quantifiers true)
(set-option :mbqi true)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :proof-mode 1)

(declare-const LB Real)
(declare-const LS Real)
(declare-const vmin Real)
(declare-const vmax Real)

(declare-const Base (_ BitVec 2))

(declare-const N Int)
(declare-fun q (Int) (_ BitVec 2))
(declare-fun |q'| (Int) (_ BitVec 2))
(declare-fun x (Int) Real)
(declare-fun |x'| (Int) Real)
(declare-fun next (Int) Int)
(declare-fun |next'| (Int) Int)
(declare-const last Int)
(declare-const |last'| Int)

(declare-const t_1 Real)
(declare-const t_2 Real)
(declare-const delta Real)

(assert (= Base #b01))
(assert (= vmin 1.0))
(assert (= vmax 2.0))
(assert (= LS 7.0))
(assert (= LB 28.0))

(assert (not (=> (and (forall ((i Int) (j Int))
           (=> (and (>= i 1) (<= i N) (>= j 1) (<= j N))
               (=> (and (not (= i j))
                        (= (q i) Base)
                        (= (q j) Base)
                        (= (next j) i))
                   (>= (- (x i) (x j)) LS))))
         (exists ((t_1 Real))
           (and (>= t_1 0.0)
                (forall ((h Int))
                  (=> (and (>= h 1) (<= h N))
                      (and (exists ((delta Real))
                             (forall ((t_2 Real))
                               (=> (and (>= t_2 0.0) (<= t_2 t_1))
                                   (and true
                                        true
                                        (or (not (= (q h) Base))
                                            (and (<= (+ (x h) (* delta t_2)) LB)
                                                 (or (not (>= (+ (x h)
                                                                 (* delta t_2))
                                                              LB))
                                                     (= t_1 t_2))
                                                 (= (|x'| h)
                                                    (+ (x h) (* delta t_1)))
                                                 (>= delta vmin)
                                                 (<= delta vmax)))
                                        true))))
                           (= (q h) (|q'| h))
                           (= (next h) (|next'| h))
                           (= last |last'|)))))))
    (forall ((i Int) (j Int))
      (or (not (and (>= i 1) (<= i N) (>= j 1) (<= j N)))
          (not (and (not (= i j))
                    (= (|q'| i) Base)
                    (= (|q'| j) Base)
                    (= (|next'| j) i)))
          (>= (+ (|x'| i) (* (- 1.0) (|x'| j))) LS))))))

(check-sat) ; toggles between unknown and sat when toggling elim-nlarith-quantifiers
```

Essentially, I'd like to create the tactic-solver corresponding to whatever solver is being used here, as this toggling behavior is what I was seeing in 4.1, but don't see in 4.3, since I can't use ELIM_QUANT via Context options anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to post your query? It would help to identify which tactics should be used. BTW, the `Repeat` combinator does not help you because `smt` is an end-game tactic. That is, it solves the problem (shows it to be `unsat` or `sat`) or does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the information about repeat.  I've added a sample query (although it being unsat is dependent on some other assertions that I'm not posting due to their length), but it shows format of the query.  Please let me know if you need more details and thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you also include the function and constant declarations? Thanks

Comment: Here's a link to a self contained example that (I imagine, assuming the SMT-LIB interface still creates a solver via mk-solver instead of via tactics) illustrates what I'm experiencing (by toggling elim-nlarith-quantifiers), with the function and constant declarations (which I also added above): http://rise4fun.com/Z3/GcaL  Also, note that I'm checking validity, so it's the negation of the assertion above---in this case with elim-nlarith enabled, the query will give sat, which is what is expected, since it being unsat depends on some (long) auxiliary assertions I'm not including

Comment: quick update: I'm still investigating the issue. The problem does not seem to be related to the quantifier elimination (qe) option. Actually, the qe module is not applicable for your example since it mixes uninterpreted functions with arithmetic in the body of the quantifiers. Your problem is on the fringe of what z3 can decide automatically. Minor modifications in the input formula or Z3 may produce this nasty side-effect. I will keep investigating the problem, and hopefully will have a better answer in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the update, please let me know if you need anything from me to help you investigate further. If the qe module is not being used, I'm a little confused about how toggling the elim-nlarith-quantifiers option causes the example's sat check to toggle between unknown and sat.  Do you know why this occurs, e.g., does this also cause nlsat or some other module to be toggled?